# Пунктуационные вопросы в статье

Tags: пунктуация

Помогите разрешить спорные моменты в статье.

*Благополучие тысяч, даже миллионов людей зависит от ценностей, навыков, умений, когда речь идет о государственных управленцах*.
Нужна ли запятая после "умений"?

*Роль руководителя особо важна в кризисные периоды.*
Особенно или особо важна?

*...руководитель, устанавливающий необходимую систему ценностей в организации, создает структуру,  долгосрочно устойчивую к коррупционным проявлениям и способную самостоятельно ликвидировать коррупциогенные очаги.*
Нужна ли запятая перед "долгосрочно"?

*За эти годы правоохранительные органы нашей страны пресекли, расследовали и раскрыли множество преступлений коррупционной направленности, в том числе в высших эшелонах власти.*
Какой знак лучше поставить перед "в том числе"?

*...насколько сложно правоохранительным органам становится выявлять, а главное пресекать и упреждать коррупцию на разных уровнях государственной и муниципальной власти.*
Нужна ли запятая перед "на разных"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Благополучие тысяч, даже миллионов людей зависит от ценностей, навыков, умений**,** когда речь идет о государственных управленцах.  Запятая перед "когда" нужна, так как она отделяет главную и придаточную части сложного предложения.

Роль руководителя **особенно** важна в кризисные периоды. - Я бы написала "особенный", но встречаются оба варианта написания в равной степени. Случай такой же, как с прилагательными "особый" и "особенный": "в значении «необычный, значительный» слова особенный и особый продолжают оставаться синонимами: особенная (особая) простота, любезность; особенное (особое) желание". [Источник](http://paronymonline.ru/%D0%9E/610)

...руководитель, устанавливающий необходимую систему ценностей в организации, создает структуру, долгосрочно устойчивую к коррупционным проявлениям и способную самостоятельно ликвидировать коррупциогенные очаги - Запятая перед словом "долгосрочно" **нужна**. Слово "долгосрочно" входит в причастный оборот "долгосрочно устойчивую к коррупционным проявлениям".

За эти годы правоохранительные органы нашей страны пресекли, расследовали и раскрыли множество преступлений коррупционной направленности**,** в том числе в высших эшелонах власти. - Достаточно будет запятой

...насколько сложно правоохранительным органам становится выявлять, а главное пресекать и упреждать коррупцию на разных уровнях государственной и муниципальной власти - Запятая перед "на разных" **не нужна**

Comment: По поводу "даже миллионов людей". Не уточнение, а присоединение, и не "даже миллионов людей", а "даже миллионов". Строго говоря, должно быть  "Благополучие тысяч, даже миллионов, людей", но на практике запятую часто не ставят. Примеры   из Нацкорпуса: Мы знаем, что сотни, может быть, **даже тысячи людей** работали одновременно с ними над теми же проблемами, но не могли найти удовлетворительного решения… [П. Л. Капица. О науке и ее организации в СССР (1935)]

Comment: Я не одна на свете, меня окружают мой брат, друг Тирадо, мои родные, близкие и товарищи, коих **сотни, даже тысячи** последуют за мной ― и вы хотите, чтобы я сказала им: «Я оставляю вас, пренебрегаю вами, не знаю вас больше!» [П. И. Вейнберг [перевод романа Л. Филипсона с немецкого]. Яков Тирадо (Испанский меч) (1887)]

Comment: Хотя одинаковое право предоставлялось всем людям шляхетского происхождения, как богатым, так и бедным, однако на деле не могло удержаться это равенство, при несоразмерности достояния землевладельцев: масса вольных шляхтичей делалась, в сущности, подчиненною знатным панам, которые обладали огромными пространствами земель и **сотнями, даже тысячами** поселений. [Н. И. Костомаров. Русская история в жизнеописаниях ее главнейших деятелей. Выпуск третий: XV-XVI столетия (1862-1875)]

Comment: Спасибо за комментарии!  Я внесла правки.