# Эти студенты обладали выдающимися, даже беспримерными(,) знаниями. Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, запятые

"Даже" в качестве союза, по грамоте.ру, *присоединяет предложение или член предложения со значением уточнения, добавления. Синтаксические конструкции с союзом «даже» **выделяются (или отделяются) запятыми**.* Вопрос в том, выделяются ли с двух сторон? Или так верно: Эти студенты обладали выдающимися, даже беспримерными знаниями.

Comment: Желательно дать ссылку на сайт.

Comment: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_148

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше так: **Эти студенты обладали выдающимися, даже беспримерными знаниями.**

Пояснение

Вариант 1. Определения с пояснительным/присоединительным значением чаще оформляются **как однородные** (ставится одна запятая). Мы как бы подбираем подходящее слово для выражения конкретного признака, раскрываем одну тему, а это характеризует однородность отношений.

Вариант 2. Это и есть однородные определения, но с добавочным значением у второго определения. Их называют **дифференцированными** однородными членамию

Answer (score 0):

Действительно, присоединительные члены предложения,вводимые в середину предложения, выделяются запятыми.

Эти студенты обладали выдающимися, даже беспримерными,знаниями.

Ср. примеры из справочника  Д. Э. Розенталя.

**Любая, даже самая сложная, проблема может быть изложена просто и доступно;
Раздались крики разносчиков, продающих всякие, даже русские, журналы (Т.);**

Comment: Наблюдается расхождение теории и практики.

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду?

Comment: На практике, в таких конструкциях с *даже* редко встретишь вторую запятую. Я "перерыл" Нацкорпус — и не нашел.

Comment: В Корпусе очень много примеров с частицей "даже". Но встречаются и примеры с союзом "даже",обособленных с двух сторон.

Comment: Академический справочник и справочник Грамоты - это новые справочники. Следовательно, если была тенденция не выделять с двух сторон присоединительные члены с двух сторон, об этом было бы сказано.

Comment: "было бы сказано" ----- Так сказано же на Грамоте: выделяются (или отделяются) запятыми. Отделяются - значит с одной стороны только. А в Нацкорпусе полно примеров с одной запятой. Я привел примеры здесь: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/436314/%d0%9f%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c%d0%b5/436322#comment444450_436322

Comment: Ключевое слово -выделяются. Отделяются тоже - в конце предложения.

Comment: Это ваша трактовка. Там не сказано "в конце предложения". Почему-то в других случаях пишут только "выделяются".